# no me hace hace el evento en jquery - button añadido con html

Tags: jquery

He añadido un botón con html en jquery.

```
function Personas(id){
    var json ={};
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/Consultas/personas",
      success: function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        var tabla = generarTabla(data.personas);
        $("#datos").html(tabla);
        
      }
    });

    
}

   function generarTabla(personas){
    var html = "<table class='table'>";
    html +="<tr><td>idPersona</td>";
    html +="<td>NIF</td>";
    html +="<td>Persona</td>";
    html +="<td>Fecha nacimiento</td>";
    html +="<td>ver domicilio</td></tr>";
    $.each( personas, function( key, value ) {
        html+="<tr>";
        html+="<td id='idPersona'>"+value.idPersona+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+value.idPersona+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+value.idPersona+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+value.idPersona+"</td>";
        html+="<td><button type='button' class='boton btn btn-primary'>ver domicilio</button></td>";
        html+="</tr>";
        
        
    });
    html += "</table>";
    return html;
}
```

cuando hago el evento no me muestra lo el alert.

```
$(".boton").click(function(){
        alert("Hola");
         
        
    });
```

Este es el html donde añado los datos:

```
<div id="datos"></div>
```

¿alguna solución?

Comment: No has añadido el botón. A una variable cuyo nombre es ***html*** **que no sabemos que contiene** le agregaste una celda con un botón dentro y luego al elemento con id **datos** que no sabemos que sea le insertas el contenido de la variable **tabla**, que no tiene nada asignado como valor. Muestra más código. Porque con lo que muestras sólo podemos decirte que no estás asignando correctamente los valores.

Comment: buenas, he añadido más código.